# Are in-app purchases supported in a native iPhone app that’s just a wrapper around an HTML5 app?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, in-app-purchase

I'm going to develop a new iphone app with html5. Then I will wrap and upload it to the app store. I just wonder if in-app purchase will be supported or not. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

The app will support in-app purchase, but not through HTML5.  You will have to implement the Objective-C code to support in-app purchases as part of your app.  So if you were hoping for a pure HTML5 solution, that is not possible.

Of course, you could do purchases through your own external service, and then you very well could come up with a pure HTML5 solution.  That might cause issues with getting the app approved by Apple, however.